# Android - Failed to allocate memory

Tags: android

I'm getting this error when trying to launch the emulator:

```
[2011-10-21 16:25:02 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2011-10-21 16:25:02 - Emulator] 
[2011-10-21 16:25:02 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2011-10-21 16:25:02 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

[image: Emulator setup]

I tried tinkering with the launch setup without success:

[image: launch setup]

The 4.0 emulator runs just fine.
Running on Windows XP.

Comment: `Device RAM size: 1024` Tried a smaller value?

Comment: What value should I put in there?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Setting device ram size to 512 fixed this.

Comment: But why does this error happen when I have 6 GB of free RAM lying around?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the memory allocation at the run time of and AVD either Reduce The RAM of that particular AVD or increase the RAM of the OS so that emulator can allocate that amount of required memory at their run time

Hope It may Help U all :)